# Getting Particleground in background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an html and css page, and i'm actually trying to get a Particleground in background, but now, it's still in the bottom of the page, like this :
[Particleground problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYi2S.png)

My code is actually :

```css
#particles {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <title>Contact form</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php include 'includes/header.html'; ?>
 <div class="contactFormContainer">
  <div class="insideContactFormContainer">
   <h1>Formulaire de contact</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="contactFormText">
   <form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <label>Nom d'utilisateur</label>
    <input class="userForm" type="text" placeholder="Nom (30 caractères max.)" name="username">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input class="emailForm" type="email" placeholder="E-mail (100 caractères max.)" name="email">
    <label>Message</label><br>
    <textarea class="messageForm" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Message (2000 caractères max.)" name="message"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" placeholder="Envoyer" name="submit">
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="scripts/Particles/jquery.particleground.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#particles').particleground({
    minSpeedX: 0.1,
    maxSpeedX: 0.7,
    minSpeedY: 0.1,
    maxSpeedY: 0.7,
    directionX: 'center', // 'center', 'left' or 'right'. 'center' = dots bounce off edges
    directionY: 'center', // 'center', 'up' or 'down'. 'center' = dots bounce off edges
    density: 10000, // How many particles will be generated: one particle every n pixels
    dotColor: '#666666',
    lineColor: '#666666',
    particleRadius: 7, // Dot size
    lineWidth: 1,
    curvedLines: false,
    proximity: 100, // How close two dots need to be before they join
    parallax: true,
    parallaxMultiplier: 5, // The lower the number, the more extreme the parallax effect
    onInit: function() {},
    onDestroy: function() {}
   });
  });
 </script>
 <div id="particles"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me solving my problem please ? :(

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I finally found :

Just put the div containing #particles to z-index: -100; in your CSS file

```css
#particles {
    z-index: -100;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <title>Contact form</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="particles"></div>
 <div class="contactFormContainer">
  <div class="insideContactFormContainer">
   <h1>Formulaire de contact</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="contactFormText">
   <form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <label>Nom d'utilisateur</label>
    <input class="userForm" type="text" placeholder="Nom (30 caractères max.)" name="username"><br><br>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input class="emailForm" type="email" placeholder="E-mail (100 caractères max.)" name="email"><br><br>
    <label>Message</label><br>
    <textarea class="messageForm" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Message (de 20 à 2000 caractères)" name="message"></textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" placeholder='Envoyer' name="submit"><br>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="scripts/Particles/jquery.particleground.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#particles').particleground({
    minSpeedX: 0.1,
    maxSpeedX: 0.7,
    minSpeedY: 0.1,
    maxSpeedY: 0.7,
    directionX: 'center', // 'center', 'left' or 'right'. 'center' = dots bounce off edges
    directionY: 'center', // 'center', 'up' or 'down'. 'center' = dots bounce off edges
    density: 10000, // How many particles will be generated: one particle every n pixels
    dotColor: '#666666',
    lineColor: '#666666',
    particleRadius: 7, // Dot size
    lineWidth: 1,
    curvedLines: false,
    proximity: 100, // How close two dots need to be before they join
    parallax: true,
    parallaxMultiplier: 5, // The lower the number, the more extreme the parallax effect
    onInit: function() {},
    onDestroy: function() {}
   });
  });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Done!

Thanks to your answers nevertheless!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set background size, for example:

```
#particles {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Or your particles div should be above the contact form.

Comment: Still not working, but a bit better : Particles are superimposed over the contact form. [Screen](http://prntscr.com/j3zw3n) So i put the <div> above the form, and change the #particles CSS

Comment: @LPepe Try to set z-index to 100 for your form.

Comment: Like <form style="z-index: 100%;"> ?

Comment: Just 100, without percentage. eg. z-index: 100;